# Scroll issue in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a Drop down when I open the drop down and move the mouse out and scroll means drop down closes.

```
  $(window).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {

    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        $("#category").data("kendoDropDownList").close();

    }
    else {
        $("#category").data("kendoDropDownList").close();
    }
});
```

Dropdown contains so many data's so inside the dropdown one scroll is there,when i scroll inside the dropdown means it also closes.(should not close)

That dropdown has a id,(should not close the dropdown when we scroll inside)

tried code:

```
  $(window).not("#category").bind('mousewheel', function (e) {

    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        $("#category").data("kendoDropDownList").close();

    }
    else {
        $("#category").data("kendoDropDownList").close();
    }
});
```

This code does not work... any idea?

Comment: Is the dropdown appended within a `<a>` tag?

Comment: [This link](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) may be helpful for fix. Also can you provide jsFiddle for this?